# How to format date range in java?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

In java, I have two calendar objects that contain a date and time. Both calendar objects are on same day but will have different times. How can I format it to look like this example:

Wednesday, November 8, 2013 10:00AM-11:00AM

Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `SimpleDateFormat` to do it, here are [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and an example:

```
String dFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy",
       tFormat = "KK:mm a";

public String formatInterval(Date from, Date to) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dFormat),
                     timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(tFormat);

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    // Day
    s.append(dateFormat.format(from));
    s.append(' ');
    // Start time
    s.append(timeFormat.format(from));
    s.append(" - ");
    // End time
    s.append(timeFormat.format(to));
    return s.toString();
}

public String formatInterval(Calendar from, Calendar to) {
    return formatInterval(from.getTime(), to.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Just one thing - `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread safe (it actually stores the data from the previous invocation), which can result in extremely strange output if accessed incorrectly.  Generally speaking, it's best to create a new instance every time you run the formatter, to avoid this problem (the string format can be saved globally, though.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you! I adapted the code to match your suggestion.

Comment: ...er, and the Java coding standard recommends only one declaration per line.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the DateUtils:

```
String range = DateUtils.formatDateRange(mContext, startDate.getMillis(), endDate.getMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_TIME);
```

(starDate and endDate are from jodaTime, if you use "Date" you need to convert it to milliseconds via Calendar)